# Can I install pytorch cpu + any specified version of cudatoolkit?

Tags: pytorch, conda

My remote has `cuda==11.0` and I want to install `pytorch` on it.

I use the command `conda install pytorch cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch -c conda-forge` but in the installation list:

```
cudatoolkit        conda-forge/linux-64::cudatoolkit-11.0.3-h15472ef_8
pytorch            pytorch/linux-64::pytorch-1.10.0-py3.8_cpu_0
```

I found that `pytorch` is a **cpu** one.

Alternatively, I substitute `11.0` with `11.1` and the installation list appears to be:

```
cudatoolkit        conda-forge/linux-64::cudatoolkit-11.1.1-h6406543_8
pytorch            pytorch/linux-64::pytorch-1.10.0-py3.8_cuda11.1_cudnn8.0.5_0
```

where `pytorch` is a **gpu** one.

My question is: **are the above two installation essentially same**? If not, how can I install `pytorch=1.10.0` with `cuda==11.0`?

I'd also like to know how does the `cuda` compatibility work? Is a `cudatoolkit==11.1` compatible with programs compiled with `cudatoolkit==11.0`?

Comment: It's just a wild guess, but I think the behaviour you see is because the pytorch channel does not have a pytorch version that built against cudatoolkit 11.0. You could check this e.g. by restricting the buildstring: `conda install "pytorch=*=*cuda11.0*" -c pytorch -c conda-forge`

Comment: That's my point. I want to install a `pytorch==1.10.0` built on `cudatoolkit==11.0`. And I want to know if it's safe to install `pytorch==1.10.0` (cpu) together with a `cudatoolkit==11.0`.

Comment: My suspicion is that if you do this you would not be able move your model to your GPU device, but get some kind of error. But I am not sure at all, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: I tried. And it seems everything works fine... I don't know if there's some potential bugs.

Comment: Sorry, I found it's not okay to install a cpu torch + cudatoolkit. I was wrong previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on whether the **pytorch** channel has built a version against the particular `cudatoolkit` version. I don't know a specific way to search this, but one can [browse what builds are available](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files) on the **pytorch** channel. For PyTorch 1.10 on **linux-64** platform it appears only CUDA versions 10.2, 11.1, and 11.3 are available.

As mentioned in the comments, one can try forcing a CUDA build of PyTorch with

```
conda create -n foo -c pytorch -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.0 'pytorch=*=*cuda*'
```

which would fail in this combination.

As for compatibility, no, the `pytorch` package builds lock in the minor version of `cudatoolkit`. For example,

[image]